# Multer on Node.js throws { Error: Unexpected field... }

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, multer, ng2-file-upload

I'm using Angular with ng2-file-upload. 
I'm getting an error:

```
{ Error: Unexpected field
at makeError (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:159:13)
at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:159:13)
at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:159:13)
at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\cDotsp27598345\Desktop\Projects\ZeoliteGlobal\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
  code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
  field: 'file',
  storageErrors: [] }
```

Here's my component's HTML: (The `addEvent` function calls the `uploadPicture` function which is further below.)

```
<form #f="ngForm"(ngSubmit)="addEvent(f.value)">
    <input type="file" name="pic" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My Angular component:

```
  uploadPicture() {
    for (const item of this.uploader.queue) {
      if (!item.isUploaded) {
        item.upload();
      }
    }
  }
```

And the uploader:

```
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: this.imgUpldURL, authToken: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`});
```

And my API end-point (I'm using a dynamic ID, if I provide the path without the dynamic ID it still doesn't work):

```
const multer = require('multer');

router.post('/uploadEventImage', authCheck, (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;
    const upload = multer({dest: 
    `../src/assets/images/news/${id}/`}).single('pic');
    console.log('called')
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          return res.end(err.toString());
        }
        console.log('done');
        res.end('File is uploaded');
      });    
});
```

This is all the multer configuration I have on my backend. The request is recieved successfully. Most of the issues I found online are caused by the input having a different name attribute, than the one passed in `.single('name')`, however as you can see, this hasn't solved anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `ng2-file-upload` is setting the name of all fields to `file`.